# AJAX requests not executing in parallel using $.when(...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My script makes around 15 ajax calls to my server. I want them to execute in parallel. I am trying to use `when` to execute a bunch of ajax requests in parallel but for some reason it's still doing them one by one.

My code is below:

```
var requests = $.map(results, function(result, i) {
    var suggestionContainer = $('<div class="suggestion-' + i + '">' + result + '</div>');
    resultsContainer.append(suggestionContainer);

    return $.get('check.php', { keyword: result }).done(function(res) {
        res = JSON.parse(res);
        suggestionContainer.append(generateSocialMediaList(res.social_media))
                           .append(generateDomainList(res.domains));
    }).fail(function() {
        suggestionContainer.remove();
    });
});

$.when(requests).done(function() {
    console.log('Complete')
}, function() {
    alert('Something Failed');
});
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

The reason why I am making 15 requests is because `check.php` makes a call to a third party API. The API is slow, and unfortunately there is no alternative. Making 15 parallel requests would be much quicker than 1 request and wait for `check.php` to complete.

The code works like so:

1. A request to `suggestions.php` is made (that's not included as it's not required to solve the problem). The results are stored in an array `results`.
2. The results (there's about 15) are returned and iterated over with `map`.
3. I insert the suggestion into the page. I then return an promise.
4. The `requests` array now contains 10-15 promises.
5. I use `when` to execute the requests in parallel (that's what I'm trying to do at least).
6. Upon success the DOM is updated and the results from `check.php` are inserted into the DOM.

Comment: Can you give us a reason why you would issue 15 http request initially (without talking about the js and css assets) ?.

Comment: `requests` contains an array of `$.get()` ajax requests. I am making 15 requests because the API server my `php` script calls has to be done sequentially. They do not accept bulk requests. The API is also slow, so rather than have the user wait for all 15 to complete, I make 15 separate calls.

Comment: @hamism Also, the requests are not happening right away. They happen when the user presses the button. I've only included the relevant code that's causing the issue.

Comment: @BugHunterUK How did you conclude that the requests are going one by one and not parallel. I used code very similar to yours and checked in browser console and requests were parallel.

Comment: @BirjuShah by monitoring the network requests in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will execute the requests with as much parallelism as the browser allows.

Browsers used to limit concurrent requests to a single domain to 6. This may have changed.

The ***responses*** to these requests will be serviced one by one because JavaScript is single-threaded, and this is what you are observing.

Also: double-check your AJAX call is not failing. `when` will reject as soon as any of the promises is rejected.

Comment: That makes sense. If it fails are the successful requests passed to the `.fail` method as they are in `.done`?

Comment: I don't think so. The error will be passed instead.